# How to always get the AR design in front of the spatial walls Unity HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am building an app for the HoloLens gen 1 device using `Unity 2018.3.13f` and `MRTK V2 RC1`. I got a simple AR design with 2 text objects and 1 rawimage object. After building the project and deploying it to the HoloLens the AR objects ends up behind the spatial mesh (you know all those spatial triangles), but I want all the objects to be in front of the wall.

**How do I accomplish this?**

The canvas is set to be on the main camera
[image: Image of canvas inspector]

I have the original settings for the `DefaultMixedRealityconfiguraitonProfile` if there is something there that needs to be changed.

This is how it looks through the hololens with the app when it does not show the mesh of the wall (sorry for the bad quality)
[image]

and this is how it looks when it falls behind the mesh
[image]

Do I need to add some mesh renderer or something on the `MainCamera` to make this possible?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "the AR objects ends up behind the spatial mesh (you know all those spatial triangles)", so thats because u set it there. In the screenshot I see that u created a screen-space-canvas. You created a HUD, that is not beneficial for an AR-project. What do you want to accomplish? Are you using spatial mapping on runtime or do you import a already scanned room? Is this ui gonna be something like a menu?

Comment: The GUI is more to see information and use as a guideline when taking a photo with a script I have. It should always show in the users field of view. Why isn't a HUD as I have created as beneficial for developing AR-projects? Do you have more details on how I should do this another way? Also I have only checked the `SpatialPerception` under capabilities in project settings, nothing else that I know of @Perazim

Comment: Regarding the topic "why not using a HUD?", you can read something for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/comfort     You want to have an immersion, something like a HUD will remaind you the whole time that u are where some vr-ar-glasses

Comment: What I used (because I also needed an alternative for an hud) is the body-locked solver from the MRTK. Its always in your view but not intrusive. You can find some information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/billboarding-and-tag-along  and here    https://medium.com/@dongyoonpark/open-source-building-blocks-for-windows-mixed-reality-experiences-hololens-mixedrealitytoolkit-28a0a16ebb61  scroll down until you see the solver system

Comment: Thanks! This is probably googleable but if I were to not check the spatialPerception capability, would this still be a problem and would the project still work for hololens? @Perazim

Comment: Activating the capability SpatialPerception will allow the mapping, but I guess it has nothing todo with your problem/question. Do you have a screenshot? But I guess I understood it right, your UI is behind the mesh, which was created by spatial mapping, right? So sometimes you cant see your UI?

Comment: @Perazim I have added two images to the post, it was them you wanted to see right (so I haven't misunderstood you).  Yes sometimes the UI hides behind the mapping. (btw is those triangles called mesh or mapping? ^^')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192967/discussion-between-perazim-and-fearlessfox).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the MRTKv2 as of 2019/5/9 has code that will auto-ensure that a specific object is positioned in between the camera and other arbitrary meshes and colliders (i.e. the spatial awareness is one such mesh, though you could imagine just having an arbitrary box or plane in the scene that would occlude that object, in which case, maybe you'd want your "in between" object to stay in between both those two types of potentially occluding things).

There used to be a script in the HTK called Tagalong.cs that would do something like this by doing raycasts from the camera to collidable object:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/htk_release/Assets/HoloToolkit/Utilities/Scripts/Tagalong.cs

This single large script I think got broken up into smaller scripts (i.e. specific behaviors in the solvers here:)

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/mrtk_release/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/Utilities/Solvers

However, from what I can tell, the specific interaction of "keep things automatically between the camera and whatever collidable object" wasn't preserved. Someone else can correct me here if I'm wrong, it looks like this wasn't a behavior that got preserved in V2.

Going forward, there are a couple of possibilities:

1) Probably file an issue on Github here (https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues) to request this feature be ported over.

2) Use the code in Tagalong.cs to add your own solver that would accomplish this (i.e. the code looks to be all there, there's just some work needed to get done to reorder it to handle what you want)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use a sprite renderer, set order in layer (into 0 or -1).
2. If you use a mesh renderer, try to deactivate dynamic occluded.
3. Try to change the hierarchy of the sorting layers under Edit-> Project Settings -> Sorting Layers

Comment: I tried adding sprite renderer to all objects in the canvas and put the order to -1 but this doesn't seem to work :/